# how to change variable levels in dataser, save the new level created and go further with a dplyr code

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to change the levels of the Death variable in my dataset (and I have done this as follows):

```
   data <- data %>% 
      mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death'))
```

and then to summarise it as follows:

```
sum_table <- data %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Death) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
  print()
```

This is the only way I know to realize both things. If I wrapped them together as follows:

```
 data %>%
      mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death'))%>%
      group_by(Treatment, Death) %>% 
      summarize(n = n()) %>% 
      mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
      print()
```

the variable Death is still coded as 1 and 0 into the original dataset.

Could you possibly suggest the term that is lacking to run the code altogether and save the new levels of that variable in the dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` to make the changes in the original data

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
data %<>%
   mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death')) %>%
   group_by(Treatment, Death) %>% 
   summarize(n = n()) %>% 
   mutate(freq = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Could you please what the symbol  %<>% is for? Generally, should it be put always at the beginning of the code? Further, do you have some shortcuts on how to type that code on the keyboard?

Comment: @creativity it is an assignment operator in magrittr.  You want only the part of the transformations to change the original object i.e. the reason I used at the top alone.

Comment: @creativity regarding the shortcuts for typing the operator, I am not aware.

Comment: thank you so much. I tested the code, converting all the dataframe into the summary object.  Actually, it assigns the final outcome to that  I just need it to the dataset I have created, while I am just trying to change the Death variable into the original variable.